# How to draw a table with shared cells?

Tags: tables

Starting from such a table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
               & Property 2 & Not property 2 \\
\hline
Property 1     & A          & B              \\
\hline
Not property 1 & C          & D              \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which gives this:

[image: Usual table]

I would like to have a table where I have a multicell which covers A and B, so all the first row, and another multicell which covers A and C, so all the first column, like this:

[image: X covers all the first column, Y all the first row]

The hard point here is that the cell A is shared between both X and Y, which is normal because it is a common property. So my problem is not about how to make multicolumn for the first nor multirow for the second, but how to make them overlap.

I though about making a Tikz figure instead in order to draw everything as I want, but considering that it is in essence a table, I wonder if it is possible to do it with the tabular environment, so I don't have to locate everything by hand in a figure.

Comment: Not very clear what is wanted. Could you post a concrete example to play with?

Comment: Is there a TeX or LaTeX package or macro that uses +-----------+ to form tables? I was only aware of markdown or org.mode for that.  Also, not to sure as to the objective of the question, maybe a MWE and a graphic mock-up of what is desired would clear things up.

Comment: I have updated my post with concrete code and pictures.

Comment: Do you really need this cell merged or is to suffice, that are lines between them are omitted?

Comment: It should be clear that there is an overlap. I could just remove the lines, but I would have one block of three cells, not two overlapping blocks.

Comment: No idea, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether I grasped your request, or what the table should mean.

Nevertheless I think this could be a possible solution, playing around with `\cline` and `multicolumn`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
               & Property 2 & Not property 2 \\
\hline
Property 1     & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Y}              \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
Not property 1 & X          & D              \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Here you remove the lines, but we still miss the colored rectangles. The important point is the overlapping between the cells. Y should cover the whole line of property 1 and X the whole column of property 2. In a way or another, it should be clear that thre is an overlap between the two.

Comment: @MatthieuVergne I did not understand that the rectangles were part of the solution. I'll elaborate later